# how to set google map scale control font size

Tags: google-maps

I have to set the scaleControl font size. i tried like below.

```
var opts = {
  zoom: 12, 
  center: latlng, 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, 
  scrollwheel: false, 
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true, 
  draggable: true,
  mapTypeControl: true, 
  panControl: false, 
  zoomControl: false, 
  scaleControl: true,
  streetViewControl: false,
  scaleControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT }
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), opts);
```

in the above code had set the font size like below

```
 scaleControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT, style:{fontSize: 10} }
```

it is not working... any suggestion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VJS Scale Control has no properties to be edit or updated to have a customized view for it. See link regarding the [ScaleOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#ScaleControlOptions).
You can try overwriting it by creating your own css, but take note that (Copyright and Terms of use) style will be affected.